# codecov.io gives error in combination with Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: php, bitbucket-pipelines, codecov

I did set up a private repo on Bitbucket to host a PHP project. For this project I also use the pipelines integration.

This is the content of my pipelines yaml file:

```
image: php:7.1.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - ./install_xdebug.sh
          - ./install_mailhog.sh
          - ./install_composer.sh
          - composer install
          - vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-clover=coverage.xml
          - if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash); fi
```

I'm able to generate a code coverage file with Xdebug:

```
Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
```

The next part is uploading this file to codecov.io but this part fails with an error

```
x> No CI provider detected.
    Testing inside Docker? http://docs.codecov.io/docs/testing-with-docker
    Testing with Tox? https://docs.codecov.io/docs/python#section-testing-with-tox
    project root: .
/dev/fd/63: line 739: git: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 739: hg: command not found
--> token set from env
    Yaml not found, that's ok! Learn more at http://docs.codecov.io/docs/codecov-yaml
==> Running gcov in . (disable via -X gcov)
==> Searching for coverage reports in:
    + .
    -> Found 1 reports
==> Detecting git/mercurial file structure
==> Reading reports
    + ./coverage.xml bytes=81581
==> Appending adjustments
    http://docs.codecov.io/docs/fixing-reports
    + Found adjustments
==> Uploading reports
    url: https://codecov.io
    query: branch=&commit=&build=&build_url=&name=&tag=&slug=&yaml=&service=&flags=&pr=&job=
    -> Pinging Codecov
HTTP 400
missing required properties: [&#39;commit&#39;]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message was a bit obscure. The real issue was a missing installation of `git` in the php 7.1.4 docker image. I solved this by adding an `apt-get` command in the pipelines config file.

> apt-get install -y git